# Is the gamma function expressible as a proper integral?

Tags: integration, gamma-function, elementary-functions

Is the gamma function expressible as a proper integral of elementary functions? You're also allowed to compose it with however many elementary functions. But strictly no limits.

[edit] So far the answers move the limit inside the integral. Is that still elementary?

Comment: By which you mean no infinite interval of integration or no singularities in the integrand?

Comment: @Chappers Yup..

Comment: An integral which has neither limit infinite and from which the integrand does not approach infinity at any point in the range of integration - this is a proper integral

Comment: If you regard every integral of the form $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty$ as "improper", you might reconsider that.  An improper integral is a limit of the form $\displaystyle\lim_{b\to\text{something}}\int_a^b$ (or similarly with the lower bound of integration).  An integral over the interval $[0,\infty)$ need not always be viewed as $\displaystyle\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_0^a$.  Lebesgue's definition of the integral of a non-negative function works just as well on unbounded intervals or on other sets of infinite measure as it does on bounded intervals${}\,\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots$ but _some_ integrals over that unbounded interval, for example $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x\,dx$, cannot be defined by Lebesgue's definition but have perfectly good limits of the form $\displaystyle\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_0^a$.  The reason for that is that the positive and negative parts both diverge to infinity. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Fair enough. I'm considering Riemann integrable functions. It would be nice if the functions had no singularities in the (compact) domain of integration. Anybody who can pull that off will get a bounty.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, although you probably won't like this much: consider
$$ \int_0^1 2x \left(-2\log{x}\right)^{n-1} \, dx. $$
Because $x (\log{(1/x)})^n \to 0$ as $x \to 0$, the integrand is continuous and bounded on $(0,1]$. Hence this is a proper integral. Now, set $x^2 = e^{-t}$, so
$$ 2x \, dx = - e^{-t} \, dt, $$
and $ -2\log{x} = -2\log{(e^{-t/2})} = t $. Then the integral becomes
$$ \int_0^{\infty} t^{n-1} e^{-t} \, dt = \Gamma(n). $$

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this:  $$\begin{align*}\Gamma(t) &= \int_{x=0}^\infty x^{t-1} e^{-x} \, dx \\ &= \int_{x=0}^1 x^{t-1} e^{-x} \, dx + \int_{x=1}^\infty x^{t-1} e^{-x} \, dx \\ &= \int_{x=0}^1 x^{t-1} e^{-x} \, dx + \int_{u=1}^0 (u^{-1})^{t-1} e^{-1/u} (-u^{-2}) \, du \\ &= \int_{x=0}^1 x^{t-1} e^{-x} + x^{-t-1} e^{-1/x} \, dx, \end{align*}$$ and the function $$f(t;x) = x^{t-1} e^{-x} + x^{-t-1} e^{-1/x}$$ is bounded on $x \in (0,1)$ for $t > 1$.